# No puedo agregar autoincrement a una llave primaria que esta relacionada en otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Cuando agrego autoincrement a una llave primaria que esta relacionada en otra tabla aparece el siguiente mensaje de error: **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'**

He intentado poner los FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS a 0 pero me manda mismo mensaje de error.

Esta es la tabla venta.

```
    CREATE TABLE `venta` (
 `idventa` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `idcliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tipo_comprobante` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `serie_comprobante` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
 `num_comprobante` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `fecha_hora` datetime NOT NULL,
 `impuesto` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
 `total_venta` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `estado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idventa`),
 KEY `fk_venta_cliente_idx` (`idcliente`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_venta_cliente` FOREIGN KEY (`idcliente`) REFERENCES `persona` (`idpersona`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Esta es la tabla detalle_venta con la que se relaciona.

```
detalle_venta
CREATE TABLE `detalle_venta` (
 `iddetalle_venta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `idventa` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `idarticulo` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `precio_venta` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 `descuento` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`iddetalle_venta`),
 KEY `fk_detalle_venta_articulo_idx` (`idarticulo`),
 KEY `fk_detalle_venta_idx` (`idventa`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_detalle_venta` FOREIGN KEY (`idventa`) REFERENCES `venta` (`idventa`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_detalle_venta_articulo` FOREIGN KEY (`idarticulo`) REFERENCES `articulo` (`idarticulo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Ya tienes registros en dicha tabla?

Comment: Al enunciar la pregunta das a entender que **id_venta es autoincremental** no obstante, en la definición de la tabla **venta** no se asigna AUTO_INCREMENT a dicha columna; al ser NOT NULL tendrá default 0, si al crear registros no pasas valor para id_venta se asignará 0 y tienes la violación de integridad referencial que comentas. Cambia la definición asignando AUTO_INCREMENT. Si las tablas tienen registros te toca dar una pequeña vuelta exportando, borrando, redefiniendo, e importando para resolver el conficto.